# JMeter Connection Timeout after 15 Min Even though increasing the Timeout is not helping

Tags: jmeter, connection, timeout, stress-testing

JMeter When the test is scheduled one of the Http request timeout happens exactly after 15 Min.

Even though tried after increasing the timeout to 30 Min in the Http Request Default header > Advance tab, In the Http requests and in the jmeter.properties file(httpclient timeout) still it is not helping gets timeout for the particular http request after 15 Min exactly, Currently tried on both Jmeter 4.0 and 5.0 as well, Need to know why its not considering the custom timeout specified.

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler **doesn't have any timeouts** so it will wait forever.

So if you remove all the timeouts - you will disable them completely. The side effect is that if your application will never respond - your test will never end.

Assuming above information my expectation is that there is a 15 minutes timeout somewhere on the **server side**, check your system under test configuration and any middleware ([reverse proxies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy), [load balancers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)), etc.)

Response time over 15 minutes is very suspicious itself, maybe the nature of application is quite exotic, however I can hardly imagine a user having to wait for 15+ minutes before the next action. I would suggest using [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) and/or [APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) tools integration with your load test, this way you will be able to get full picture of what's going on during your testing on the server side. If you don't have any monitoring tools in place you can consider using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)